# Are there timestamps on each Cloud Firestore document that are accessible from Python via the Admin API?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm trying to write a Python script that iterates a collection in Firebase and takes external actions using data from each document matching the where() criteria.

My thinking is that I can run this script periodically (for instance, every 15 minutes or every hour), select only those documents that have been created or modified in the preceding period, and have the script create static HTML documents containing Open Graph and Twitter Card tags, so links into my existing Angular app show relevant information from dynamically-generated pages.

Here's the code I've written so far:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pprint
import datetime
import requests
import codecs
import json
import sys

import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

#
# The purpose of this script is to generate static document pages for
# Facebook OpenGraph and Twitter meta tag exposure.
#
# We run this code at /home/app-name/utilities on the third-party app server at our inexpensive hosting provider.
#
# Use a service account

cred = credentials.Certificate('./App-Data-Mover-Key.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint({u'sys.argv': sys.argv})

try:
    docs = [snapshot.reference for snapshot in db.collection(u'documents').where(u'what goes here?').get()]

    for docref in docs:
        doc = docref.get().to_dict()
        pp.pprint(doc)

        # Create the file and write out HTML stub here.

finally:
    print("Done!\n")
```

My question is, are there timestamps representing creation and last modification of each Cloud Firestore document that I can reference in the where clause when I'm building up the snapshot?

Comment: One way I have exposed the contents of a few selected documents is to make the where clause something like ```where(u'id', u'==',' 500)```. The ```id``` attribute in my application is unique, so I only get one document at a time.

When I do this I get output to the console from the ```pp.pprint(doc)``` statement. ```doc``` contains a lot of attributes, but none of them appears to be timestamps automatically inserted by Cloud Firestore.

Comment: My next step is to inspect ```docref``` to see if it has timestamp data that I haven't seen up to now.

Comment: Note that the where clause above should be ```where(u'id', u'==', 500)```. I made a mistake in trying to format the markdown correctly.

Comment: ```pp.pprint(docref)``` returns ```<google.cloud.firestore_v1beta1.document.DocumentReference object at 0x7ffa4854fa50>```. How do I decode it?

Obviously ```doc = docref.get().to_dict()``` turns it into a dictionary, but I am hoping that ```docref``` itself contains some metadata that doesn't end up in the dict.

Comment: There are no automatically maintained/updated timestamps in documents. You need to create those attributes and keep them up-to-date yourself. The `firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP`  constant can be used for this. See examples at https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/firestore/document.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1beta1.document.DocumentReference.update

Comment: Thanks very much @HiranyaJayathilaka. I wasn't certain from looking at the documentation if automatically-maintained timestamps were a feature of Cloud Firestore or not. Every tutorial I looked at talked about creating such timestamps, but non talked about accessing ones that already existed. I didn't want to make a conclusion on my own and end up being incorrect.

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka your comment is probably the best answer to the question I asked.